# What is the easiest way to localize SSRS Report with VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, reporting-services

I'd like to know if there's a norm for this task since VS2012 SSRS does not support resx files. It would be so much easier this way but we just can't add resx files to a SSRS Report.

I know that you can create a custom assembly to do this, but is this the best approach?

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to localize? Parameter prompts?

Comment: I want to localize text. So if there's a text like "Hi" in English it should write "Salut" in a French report

Comment: Of course, I won't have control over the data that comes from the Dataset but the presentation should be able to be both English and French

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a custom assembly in .NET and a method to retrieve the localized string.

```
//Class to retrieve the localized value
public static class LocalizedValue
{    
   public static string GetString
    (string localeSensitiveResource, string cultureInfoName)
   {
    //
   }
}
```

In your report you would access it  like this:

```
=Code.LocalizedValue("REPORTHEADER", Parameters!ReportCulture.Value)
```

Refer to this code project for more information:

[Localization of SRS Reports](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33355/Localization-of-SSRS-Reports)

Answer (score 1):

For Dynamics AX this is pretty simple.

If you keep your layout the same, add translations for the labels you are using in your expressions.
(`=Label!@SYS1234`)

If the layout differs, add a new design to your report, e.g. `FreeTextInvoice`.

Comment: Yeah, the layout must be the same. So I should simply ad translations for the labels? Can you explain a bit more how the =Label works? Thanks!

Comment: @BenLefebvre That's how I do it, yes.

Comment: So if I want a label which content let's say "Noodles" in english how would I write the =Label expression if I want it to write "Nouilles" in a French report? Thanks

Comment: @BenLefebvre You'd only write the `=Label!@MDL1234` once. In AX you'd translate the labels using the label editor. If you're not using AX, perhaps try [the following](http://www.keepitsimpleandfast.com/2011/09/localization-of-your-ssrs-reports.html)